# Displaying sub menu items sequentially

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, menuitem, submenu

I'm creating a navigation bar and I'm trying to add this effect : when you hover over a main menu item, each sub menu item under it appear with a slight delay. Like one after the other.

I have somewhat done it but it's very buggy. Sometimes the delays take too long, sometimes the second sub item appears before the first one! And worst of all, when you take the mouse off the main item, the list under it disappears! Altogether its not very smooth. Here's the code I have now.

**HTML**

```
<div id="navbar">
    <ul id="main-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Members</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Events</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub item 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Publications</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub item 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub item 6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#navbar { width:550px; height:30px; position:relative; float:right; right:-7px; top:30px; }

#main-menu { width:100%; float:right; list-style:none; }

#main-menu li { float:left; }

#main-menu li a { display:block; text-decoration:none; color:#000; background-color:#FC0; padding:8px; margin-right:10px; }

#main-menu li ul { display:none; z-index:999; }

#main-menu li:hover ul { display:block; position:absolute; }

#main-menu li li { display:block; float:none; }
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('#main-menu li a').hover(function()
    {
        $(this).animate({
            backgroundColor : '#C60'
        },200);

        $('#main-menu ul li').each(function(e) {
            $(this).delay(e * 200).hide().fadeIn(200);                                     
        });

    }, function(){
        $(this).animate({
            backgroundColor : '#FC0'
        },200);
    });

});​
```

Please see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/isuru_nan/Hjxp5/1/) fiddle here.

How can I make it a smooth, functional one?

Comment: You need you need to use `setTimeout` and `cleartimeout` instead of `delay`. In this way you can control the timeouts better. `delay` uses the same thing but you don't have the timeout pointer to clear the timouts once you stop hovering, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use CSS transitions instead to fade in the menu items (and to set the background colours). All you need to do is calculate the transition delay for each child li using jQuery on the first load. Eg:

```
$('#main-menu li ul li').each(function() {
    var delay = $(this).index() * 200 + 'ms';

    $(this).css({
        '-webkit-transition-delay': delay,
        '-moz-transition-delay': delay,
        '-o-transition-delay': delay,
        'transition-delay': delay
    });                  
});
```

Then set the appropriate transitions on the elements. Here's a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hjxp5/8/

Comment: Thanks Christian, that's nice way to go about it but CSS transitions aren't fully supported in every browser as of now, right? So that would be a problem.

Comment: They're supported in all major browsers, excluding anything under IE10. You could also add the `-ms-transition` property for further support. Don't forget that this menu still works in older browsers, it just won't animate. And if someone uses a browser that doesn't support CSS transitions, they don't care about any fancy effects. Code for the future, not for the past.

Comment: I understand. You've made a good, valid point. Thank you again. I'll be using this method. :)